# Dart - Re-using Flutter widgets sometime contains wrong data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-widget

I have a Flutter web application that displays multiple user profiles on a card within a Row. The cards can each flip over to reveal more information via this library:

https://pub.dev/packages/flip_card

The application uses WebSockets and receives a JSON list of user details which maps to a User dart class, and as soon as new list arrives on a socket, we create a widget and add it to a widgetList and wrap it in a setState():

```
 webSocket.onMessage.listen((e) {
          final List receivedJsonUserList = json.decode(e.data);
          final List<User> userListFromSocket =
              receivedJsonUserList.map((item) => User.fromJson(item)).toList();
          userListFromSocket.forEach((newUser) {
            setState(() {
              widgets[newUser.user.id] = UserDetails(user: newUser);
              widgetList = widgets.entries.map((entry) => entry.value).toList();
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

The widget is drawn like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context, sizingInformation) => Scaffold(
        drawer: sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.mobile
            ? NavigationDrawer()
            : null,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Scrollbar(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: widgetList),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The code works 90% of the time, but occasionally the wrong data is on the back of a card. So User 1 will have User 2's data on the back, etc.

Am I doing this correctly? Is there an obvious issue with this implementation? I tried to create a seperate widget for each user and it seems to resolve the issue but re-using widgets surely has to be possible.

Comment: Try adding Unique keys to the widgets

Comment: Would a unique key for each card suffice here?

Comment: If the data is correct in that widget and still it is showing any previous data, then unique key can help to update the widget.